# Perl Parsing CSV Efficient with Embedded Commas and Adding To Database

Tags: database, perl, csv, regex-negation

How do you apply regular expressions to an array. While reading in my csv file I applied this...

```
        s/, /- /g;
        s/1,000/1000/g;
```

But after I put the data in my multidimensional array I don't know how to insert the commas back to my fields.

Comment: My output looks like this...  "Total farm value- potatoes (dollars x 1000)"

Comment: I am not fully with your question. You remove the comma but want to put it back again?

Comment: Have you looked into using join? ` perldoc join `

Comment: The regular way to allow commas within a data field is to surround the field with double quotes. `1,000` would become `"1,000"`. CPAN modules such as `Text::CSV` support this convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, there are a few CSV modules you can use to achieve this easily, however in some cases I know people do not have access to, or cannot install packages for reasons. Therefore, this should help if that is the case.

If I am getting you correctly, you are trying to write fields from CSV, which has embedded commas.If this is the case, these imbedded comma fields should have parenthesis or quotes around them in order to ensure they are not seen as the CSV's comma delimited fields. We can then just grab all of the data in your CSV. In this case we will have a csv that uses parenthesis, quotes and both to display data that is using embedded commas:

These show the CSV commas:

```
"Potatoes 1,000", (Tomatoes, 200), "(GemSquash, 1,029.95)"
                ^                ^
```

These are embedded commas:

```
"Potatoes 1,000", (Tomatoes, 200), "(GemSquash, 1,029.95)"
           ^               ^                  ^  ^
```

So the below will search and replace the data using the parenthesis and the double quotes to determine which are csv commas and which are embedded.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = '(Potatoes 1,000), "Tomatoes, 200", "(GemSquash, 1,029.95)"';
my $query = qr/(?: "\( ( [^()""]* ) \)" |  \( ( [^()]* ) \) |  " ( [^"]* ) " |  ( [^,]* ) ) , \s* /x;
my @results = grep defined, "$string," =~ /$query/g;
print "$_\n" for @results;
```

***RESULTS***

```
Potatoes 1,000
Tomatoes, 200
GemSquash, 1,029.95
```

Answer (score -2):

For parsing CSV, use a CPAN module like [`Text::CSV`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV). You can the use the regex on the values returned.